# How to intuit 'unless'?

Tags: logic

I already know, and so  ask NOT about, the proof of: [A unless B =  A if not B =  Either A or B](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/a/12241/5306).
Because I ask only for intuition, please do NOT prove this or use truth tables.

**My problem:** I want to avoid memorisation. So whenever I see **unless**, I always need to pause for 5 minutes to rewrite the sentence, in order to determine the meaning. This pause reveals deficiency in my knowledge, which I must resolve, because it smothers me.
So please help me dig deeper. How can this conjunction be naturalised?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is any deeper intuition there.  It is just a matter of linguistic convenience.

But if it helps, the word is part of a set of words in English, including 'lest', 'else' and 'except', that are generally related to exceptions in rules or intentions. (I only start with the least common one first because it is the one most closely related historically.)

"I dare not wear wool lest it rain", meaning I want to, but will contradict my own wish for a good reason.  I wear wool by choice, unless it is going to rain.

"You must choose a meat option, or else you should mark may 'vegetarian' if you do not eat meat.", meaning there is a general rule, but sometimes there is an allowed variation.  Choose a meat, unless you are vegetarian.

Or, of course, "It is illegal for adults to ride a bicycle on the sidewalk except when accompanying minors under the age of 13."  Meaning again that there is a rule, but also an exception.  (Obviously the source of the word 'exception'.)  Bike in the street, unless protecting children.

I hope that helps.

(But if it does, that means this question did not belong here, but instead belonged on English Language and Usage SE instead.  Ask questions of logic here, unless they are really about Engish and not logic...)