# How to simplify: Unless, if A, B, then C

Tags: logic

[This ELU question](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/187083/50720) motivated the following, but I abbreviate all clauses. Also, lest 'then' be written twice in the same sequence of events, interpret the adverb 'then' to precede the adverb 'thence'.

> *Unless* is a kind of negative of *if*—think of [...] *unless* as very much like “if . . . *not.”* [...]
>
> > [1.] Unless,  if A, [then] B,  [thence] C.
>
> [2.] In other words,   *if* it is the case that  *if* A, then B,   then[ce] C;
> otherwise, C. There are *two* conditionals operating here.

In general,  [unless X, Y  =  X, if not Y.](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/23440/8572)  =   [3.]  If not `Y`, then **X**.

In [1.] above,   **X  =  if A, [then] B**.    And  `Y = C`.

Then using [3.], [1.] becomes:

[4.]  If not `C`, then  **if A, [then] B**.

But [4.] differs from [2.]; so which is wrong?
Please explain and show all steps and thought processes.

Comment: Why do you think 4 differs from 2?

Answer (score 1):

There are three standard ways of describing the logical form of "A unless B" where A and B are sentences:

```
a. A or B
b. If not-A then B
c. If not-B then A
```

These three are, happily, logically equivalent.

In your description, item [2] uses one form (my b) and item [4] uses another form (my c).

Comment: unless you see the very ugly person in front of the car, floor the accelerator.
floor the accelerator or see the very ugly person in front of the car. hey, If not floor the accelerator, then see the very ugly person in front of the car.